# How to Bundle products based on customer selection?

Tags: magento2, category, cart, plugin, bundled-product

What is the best approach to achieve a step-by-step walkthrough experience, prompting customers to select items from 3 categories and sell them as a bundle with a single dynamic price during checkout?

> Example: A customer is expected to select a Shirt, Pants and Bag from each product category. All these need to be bundled with a 4th item included in each order. See images for example mockup.

Is the better approach to...

A. Create a bundle product and add each product category item as an option, then edit codes to show images, product details etc., allowing the bundle product page to look like a typical product category select page.

B. Create a plugin to allow product selected/add-to-cart to be automatically bundled with a 4th item with a single dynamic price in the cart.

[image: Fig 1. Customer selected a shirt from the Shirt Category]
**Fig 1.** Customer selected a shirt from the Shirt Category

[image: Fig 2. Customer selected a shirt, Pants and Bag from the respective Category]
**Fig 2.** Customer selected a shirt, Pants and Bag from the respective Category

[image: Fig 3. Products selected are bundled under one item with dynamic pricing in the shopping cart.]
**Fig 3.** Products selected are bundled under one item with dynamic pricing in the shopping cart.